# Adjust gui dependant on a file that has been selected

Tags: python, csv, qt-designer, pyqt5

I'm using QT designer to develop a gui which allows you to select dates and certain channels. The channels are all in a csv file along with the possible dates you may select.

Is there anyway to limit the dates you may be able to select in the calendar if you have selected the file for it to read within the gui? 
I'd also like it to read the channels in and present them as options

I'm sure this is part of a major part of GUI design and if anyone could point out some documentation if it is too long for an answer it would be really appreciated

**EDIT**

The data in my csv is in the format:

```
DATE        A   B   C   D
01/01/2001  1   2   3   4
02/01/2001  5   6   7   8
03/01/2001  9   10  11  12
04/01/2001  13  14  15  16
05/01/2001  17  18  19  20
```

Comment: Please show how your data is present in csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the QCalendarWidget Class. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465490/how-can-calendar-widgets-particular-cells-be-coloured), it will help you how to extend QCalendarWidget.